# Переполнение текста в блоке привилегий

Tags: дефект, предложение, дизайн

Добрый день! На сколько я понимаю, подобные вопросы нужно задавать тут.

На странице профиля пользователя на вкладке «Активность» в блоке «След. привилегия» происходит переполнение текста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Видел, что вопрос этот уже неоднократно задавали. Но там не приводят нужного в данной ситуации решения.

Comment: Так надо было ответ в существующей теме писать

Comment: Если вопрос уже был задан, не следует задавать его снова. Лучше поднимите обсуждение в старом. Вопрос обсуждали как на мете, так и в чате. В часности, было предложено просто сократить надпись до 2-ух строк.

Comment: Так мне как лучше поступить? Перенести ответ туда, а этот вопрос удалить?

Comment: @AlexanderBragin Вопрос в любом случае закроют, раз он уже есть. На вашем месте я бы перенёс ответ в существующий вопрос, а этот удалил. Но решать вам!

Comment: Ответ туда добавил. Но! Не могу редактировать вопрос. Нужно как минимум тег `дизайн` добавить + заголовок более профессионально написать — «Переполнение...» хотя бы добавить куда-нибудь.

Comment: @EgorTrutnev да сейчас удалю. Спасибо.

Comment: Не, сам я удалять не буду) — _Мы не рекомендуем удалять вопросы, на которые даны ответы. Это лишит будущих читателей знаний по описанной проблеме. Частое удаление вопросов с ответами может привести к тому, что вам будет запрещено задавать новые вопросы. Вы действительно хотите выполнить удаление?_ **Но ответ перенес.**

Comment: @AlexanderBragin думаю переноса будет достаточно. Добавлять тег или менять заголовки не требуется. Про проблему администрация ruSO уже знает.  
P.S. За частое удаления заблокируют доступ. Вы собираетесь часто писать дубликаты?

Comment: @EgorTrutnev это не от меня будет зависить. А от того, на сколько ясно будут пользователи свои мысли выражать в вопросе. Чтобы можно было легко найти существующий вопрос... К тому же я искал вопрос с тегом [`дизайн`](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bдизайн%5D+привилегии), потому что это тема явно касается верстки. Почему тег не был добавлен и/или отредактирован — вопрос не ко мне)

Comment: @AlexanderBragin К Вам то у меня нет претензий. Я про то писал, что, если удалить один вопрос - бан за это вам не дадут.

Comment: @EgorTrutnev да я тоже без претензий) Только недавно активно начал Stack Overflow пользоваться. Пока ещё не все нюансы знаю... — спасибо тем, что отвечает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Возможное решение

Изменить следующие стили (/* + */ — что было добавлено)

```css
.s-progress-bar._privilege .-info .-icon {
    margin-right: 4px;
    width: 14px;
    color: #6a737c;
    margin-left: 4px; /* + */
}

.s-progress-bar._privilege .-info .-label {
    margin-left: 2px;
    white-space: nowrap;  /* + */
    overflow: hidden;  /* + */
    text-overflow: ellipsis;  /* + */
    display: inline-block;  /* + */
}
```

Не забыть к `span` добавить `title`. Чтобы при наведении можно было прочитать полностью статус.

```
<span class="g-col fl-none -label" title="Просмотр голосов, карточка участника, которую можно расширить">Просмотр голосов, карточка участника, которую можно расширить</span>
```

#### Как будет выглядеть после изменений

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]